# How to create your own JSON file locally?

Tags: javascript

I was watching a YT video explaining JSON/AJAX ([link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJesac0_Ftw)) and in the video, the speaker uses a github.io website to link to their own JSON file ([link to file](https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json)). Is it possible to create your own JSON file?

Comment: Yes, you can create a JSON file.

Comment: JSON is just a text file in a certain format.  Can you create a text file?  If so, you can create a JSON document.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a standard for organizing text with a certain structure.

You can create your own JSON file by saving a text file from an editor with the .json extension.